# Совместить подписи в одно криптосообщение

Tags: python, ssl, криптография, openssl

К одному файлу создано несколько подписей разными людьми. Как то можно собрать один файл из нескольких? Может через asn1crypto или ещё как?

```
openssl pkcs7 -in q.sig -in w.sig -out all.sig
```

Не прокатило.

Comment: В каком формате подписи? Вы уверены, что они PKCS#7? Если они действительно в PKCS#7, то  это PEM или DER? DER достаточно перевести в PEM формат, а PEM подписи можно безболезненно слить в один файл. В результате будет файл из нескольких блоков `-----BEGIN PKCS7----- ... -----END PKCS7-----`

Comment: Что касается объединения нескольких подписей в формате PKCS#7 в один PKCS#7 объект, то это возможно. Цифровая подпись в PKCS#7 кодируется объектом типа [`SignedData`](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/formal-language/itu-t/x/x420/1999/PKCS7.html#PKCS7.signed-data). В этом объекте есть множество сертификатов и множество подписей (SET OF SignerInfo). Нужно из каждой подписи извлечь сертификат и SignerInfo, объединить все сертификаты в один SET, объединить все SignerInfo тоже в один SET, и затем закодировать обратно в ASN.1 DER/PEM

Comment: @PakUula при паровозе из pem программы проверки, в том числе openssl-verify , принимают только один из контейнеров p7, остальные игнорируются.

Comment: Разобрать и собрать ... Ищу парсер, может пример какой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой скрипт на Python, который строит объединённую подпись из двух подписей:

```py
"""Test of ASN.1 processing of PKCS#7 messages"""
import glob
import asn1tools

print("Processing ASN specification")
asn_files = glob.glob("*.asn")
cms = asn1tools.compile_files(asn_files, codec="der")

id_signedData = "1.2.840.113549.1.7.2"


def parse_signature_as_sigData(fileName):
    with open(fileName, "rb") as sigFile:
        sigBytes = sigFile.read()
    sigMsg = cms.decode("ContentInfo", sigBytes)
    if sigMsg["contentType"] != id_signedData:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported content type: {sigMsg['contentType']}")
    # sigMsg["content"] просто бинарная строка, парсер оставляет тип ANY как есть.
    sigData = cms.decode("SignedData", sigMsg["content"])

    return sigData


def sigData_to_CryptoMessage_DER(sigData):
    # Сначала SignedData кодируется в бинарную строку (тип ANY)
    sigDataBytes = cms.encode("SignedData", sigData)
    # Полное сообщение состоит из идентификатора контента и контента в виде двоичной строки
    msg = {"contentType": id_signedData, "content": sigDataBytes}
    return cms.encode("ContentInfo", msg)


print("Loading sig1.der")
sig1 = parse_signature_as_sigData("sig1.der")
print("Loading sig2.der")
sig2 = parse_signature_as_sigData("sig2.der")

# поле crls необязательное в SignedData
if not "crls" in sig1:
    sig1["crls"] = []
if not "crls" in sig2:
    sig2["crls"] = []

print("Combining the signatures")
sig1["certificates"] += sig2["certificates"]
sig1["crls"] += sig2["crls"]
sig1["signerInfos"] += sig2["signerInfos"]

print("Writing the combined signature to both.der")
der = sigData_to_CryptoMessage_DER(sig1)
with open("both.der", "wb") as file:
    file.write(der)

print("Done")
```

Полный вариант c необходимыми спецификациями ASN, сертификатами и ключами, файлом `lorem.md`, файлами подписей:
https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/tree/main/python/1530987

Кодек строится из спецификации

```py
asn_files = glob.glob("*.asn")
cms = asn1tools.compile_files(asn_files, codec="der")
```

Я немного подпилил эту спецификацию, чтобы `asn1tools` не падали на ней.

Дальше всё просто. Файлы парсятся как `SignedData`

```
sig1 = parse_signature_as_sigData("sig1.der")
sig2 = parse_signature_as_sigData("sig2.der")
```

поля подписей объединяются

```
# поле crls необязательное в SignedData
if not "crls" in sig1:
    sig1["crls"] = []
if not "crls" in sig2:
    sig2["crls"] = []

sig1["certificates"] += sig2["certificates"]
sig1["crls"] += sig2["crls"]
sig1["signerInfos"] += sig2["signerInfos"]
```

объединённая подпись сохраняется в файл

```
der = sigData_to_CryptoMessage_DER(sig1)
with open("both.der", "wb") as file:
    file.write(der)
```

Comment: Вещь конечно хорошая, но пользоваться этим не буду. Тут очень завязано на спецификации - не уверен что хочу следить что какие-то специфические поля не потерялись.

Comment: @eri спецификация официальная, из RFC. Исправлена одна опечатка (запятая не там) и в поле ContentInfo.content тип изменён с`EXPLICIT ANY DEFINED BY` на `EXPLICIT ANY`. Если новый стандарт не придумают, работать будет вечно :)